# CSS hover bubble does not seem out

Tags: html, css

Hello friends I have a problem with mouse hover on a `div`.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/JobPEY)** from *codepen.io*

So you can see in this demo when you hover over image the bubble will be shown. But the bubble does not seem out.

Here is the **HTML** code:

```
<div class="container"
<div class="present_wrp">
<div class="wo_wrp2 wo-wrp2">
  <div class="wo_content2">
      <div class="ornekoto"><img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/26625.png" width="267" height="250" /><div class="ornot"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS** code:

```
.container {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  margin-top:100px;
}
.wo_wrp *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wo-wrp2 {
    float: left;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
position: relative;
width: 300px;

}

.wo_content2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #97a8bb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
}
.wo_content_t2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding:5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #97a8bb;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
}
.wo-wrp2:after {
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 20px 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(113, 145, 182, 0.5);
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;

}
.ornekoto{
    float:left;
    width:267px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#307cdc;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -o-border-radius:3px;
    -o-border-radius:3px
    }
.ornot 
{
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
height: 500px;
padding: 0px;
background: #307cdc;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
display:none;
margin-top:-755px;
}

.ornot:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 0;
border-color: #307cdc transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
bottom: -15px;
left: 58px;
}
.ornekoto:hover .ornot{
    display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `overflow: hidden` on `.wo_content2` which prevents your bubble from popping out of it's parent container (because the "overflow" is hidden). Use a clearfix instead:

```
.wo_content2 {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 15px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   /*overflow:hidden;*/ <---------- remove
   border: 1px solid #97a8bb;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -o-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius:3px;
}

.wo_content2:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogYvZL)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `overflow:hidden;` set. If you swap that for a clearfix it will work fine.

Overflow hidden is keeping the height of the container, so you need to first add a clearfix to the div (a clearfix allows the div to keep the height of the floated elements within it).

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Next all you need to do is to add this to the surrounding div:

```
<div class="wo_content2 cf">
```

And then remove the overflow hidden property

```
.wo_content2{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

#### Demo here:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/NPbKpz